# How to open a file with out downloading it to my computer

Tags: c#, file-io, datagridview

I am just trying to open a files that are uploaded to my gridview, without downloading it.
But when i am trying to open it its giving me error called illegal path.
Any ideas.

```
    private void cncInfoDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.
        //make sure user select only single cell
        //and the cell have a value in it
        if (SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(1))
        {

           OpenAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);
        }

     }


  private void OpenAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        if (SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(1))
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string strfilename = fileDialog.FileName;  // gets the path
                    string result;                              //initilizate the filename variable
                    result = Path.GetFileName(strfilename);
                    //string strfilename = File.ReadAllText("");
                    cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = strfilename;
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(strfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    using (var textReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        var content = textReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the path that you are trying to open?

Comment: @slugster path can be anything.. its differs from file to file.

Comment: Without seeing a path how can we know why it is illegal? We can't see what is in your grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..
Thanks guys...

```
private void OpenAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        if (SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(1))
        {
            string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString(); // stores in string s
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s);   ///Open the file
        }
     }
```